# How to overcome the blinking white underscore?

Tags: bootloader

What's keeping me from moving forward is that even USB Live drives (Ubuntu 16.04, Boot Repair Disk) are halted by this blinking white underscore.

Situation: Dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.10. Old pc: Asus motherboard (M4A78E) EPU, not EFI. AMD Phenom II X3 710, 8Gb ram, EVGA Geforce GTX 560 (but no longer plugged - using motherboard graphics now).

It had been working just fine until about a week ago, neither OS is available any more. Instead either one halts the loading with nothing but a blinking white underscore on a black screen.
Whether I load Grub2 from the local HD, or from a USB Live drive.
Unfortunately using nomodeset or nouveau.modeset=0 won't help, on either case.
It did pass the Memtest86 test.
The only thing that's new lately, would be the Windows updates, namely the Creative update. Before it was running Windows 10 just fine. Yes, I know it's been advised to fall back to an older Kernel in this case. It didn't help either. I still end up with that white blinking underscore.

Comment: There's no EFI, only Legacy BIOS :(

Comment: I had old boards that had trouble to boot from USB stick. They worked from USB Disk drive with a DVD, though. Maybe worth a trial.

Comment: I tried with Zesty Zapus 17.04 in a DVD, but it couldn't get to read and load the files. I know the DVD is good as I did test it and confirmed it runs by booting with it using my newer pc. It did attempt to start (in the old pc), but that's as far as it went. Tomorrow I'll try with an older release, like Trusty Tahr 14.04.

Comment: That sounds really weird. Maybe you should consider a harware problem. I would remove all except RAM, use an IDE/SATA DVD. I have run several asus boards from that family with recent ubuntu's without issue. 16.04 was definitetly ok, 16.10 as well.

Comment: I did as you suggested. Stripped it down to nothing but 1 memory stick of 2Gb, and 1 DVD player. This time it went a tad further. It loaded 2 small icons at the bottom of a purple screen, of a keyboard on the left, and a circle with a person inside on the right. Then it went to the usual blinking underscore.  However by plugging the HDs back, I've got the Grub back. The Ubuntu choice at the top brings me right away to that blinking underscore. But going with Windows recovery, triggered an event to try to repair it.

Comment: Unfortunately it stayed showing that same message with the circling dots for over an hour. Could it be that the problem lies with either the motherboard, or the CPU? I mean, what else is left?

Comment: I found that the CPUs are acutally quite robus. I had very exotic MB behaviour and thought the CPU was fried, but it worked fine in another MB. There is a lot a possible faults in an MB. If you have bad capacitors or cracks it might work sometimes or only some parts may work partly. really hard to tell without a replacement board of the same type. I guess chances are good that you are looking at a bad board.